# How to add hover effect to img placed in parent container

Tags: html, css

How can I add a hover effect to the `img` after mouse is over link `Text` using CSS?

```
<div class="myTextContainer">
    <p>
        <a href="#">
            <img height="128" width="128" title="icon1" alt="icon1" src="icon1.png" ">
        </a>
    </p>
    <h2>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: In CSS isn't possible to target parent or previous sibling elements. Put image and 'Text' into one link.

Comment: Take a look at my post, just updated... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some JavaScript. In my case i added html attribute onmouseover and onmouseleave to call a javascript function. fun1 on hover and fun 2 onleave. I added id hover on my image and i said on each function to get the element of the id hover which is my image and change the backgroundColor='blue'. On hover i set it to blue and onleave i set it to red. You can change other elements like the src by doing style.src='here/put/the/image/source/img.png' and add different src on hover or leave. If you need more info leave a comment. Did this help?

```js
function fun1(){
  document.getElementById("hover").style.backgroundColor='blue';
}
function fun2(){
  document.getElementById("hover").style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

```css
#hover{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myTextContainer">
    
        <a href="#">
            <img id="hover" height="128" width="128" title="icon1" alt="icon1" src="icon1.png">
        </a>
    
    <h2>
        <a href="#" onmouseover="fun1()" onmouseleave="fun2()">Text</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

-------- Or by doing this without script tag or file --------

```css
#hover{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myTextContainer">
    <p>
        <a href="#">
            <img id="hover" height="128" width="128" title="icon1" alt="icon1" src="icon1.png">
        </a>
    </p>
    <h2>
        <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('hover').style.backgroundColor='blue';" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('hover').style.backgroundColor='red';">Text</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML markup and put both, icon and text into one link.

```
<h2>
    <a>
        <img ...>
        TEXT
    </a>
</h2>
```

Than you can use simply

```
a:hover {color: red;} /* red text 'TEXT' */
a:hover img {border: 1px solid green}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `h2` and `p` are siblings but you want to add hover on `h2 img` which is before `p`, you cannot do it with CSS. You need javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[1].addEventListener('mouseover', fn, false);
document.querySelectorAll('a')[1].addEventListener('mouseout', fn2, false);
function fn(e) {
 if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Text') {
  document.querySelector('img[src="icon1.png"]').className = 'hover';
 }
}
function fn2(e) {
 if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Text') {
  document.querySelector('img[src="icon.png"]').className = '';
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could declare:

```
.myTextContainer a:hover img {
// your CSS
}
```

Comment: The question is about 'Text' hyperlink. Not the one containing image. You cannot go to previous sibling in css.

Comment: The `img` is not in the `h2`. The above CSS won't work.